# magmablas_dgemm not working for larger grid size

Tags: c, cuda, blas, magma

I am new to using cuda and the magma libraries. I'm trying out some functions on a test problem, a 2D heat equation. The code I wrote seemed to work perfectly for grid sizes of 32, 64, and 128. But it produced wrong results for grid sizes of 256 or larger. I am only posting part of the code here, just enough to reproduce the error. Transferring the final matrix and looking at it in matlab shows that the second call to magmablas_dgemm introduced errors into the solution.

Is there anyone out there who can see why this code would break for larger grid sizes?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    // Get parameters for problem set up
    int side_width = atoi(argv[1]); //assuming square grid, N/32 integer 
    double dx = 2.0 / (side_width-1);
    double dt = 0.25 * dx;
    //double Tend = dt*3;// 0.5; 


    // create memory pointers for derivative operator matrices and solution matrix
    double* U;
    double* Dleft;
    double* Dright;
    double* dev_U;
    double* dev_Dleft;
    double* dev_Dright;

    //initialize the MAGMA system
    magma_init();

    magma_int_t N = side_width;

    // temp variables required by MAGMA functions
    magma_int_t *piv, info, err;
    piv = (magma_int_t*)malloc(N*sizeof(magma_int_t));


    // Allocate memory for matrices on host and device
    err  = magma_dmalloc_cpu(&U, N*N);
    err += magma_dmalloc_cpu(&Dleft, N*N);
    err += magma_dmalloc_cpu(&Dright, N*N);
    err += magma_dmalloc(&dev_U, N*N);
    err += magma_dmalloc(&dev_Dleft, N*N);
    err += magma_dmalloc(&dev_Dright, N*N);  

    if (err){
        printf("error in allocation. err number = %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }


    // zero out matrices (not efficient but correct)
    for (int k=0; k<N*N; ++k ){
        U[k] = 1.0;
        Dleft[k] = 0.0;
        Dright[k] = 0.0;
    }


    //create derivative operator matrices
    double a = dt/2.0/dx/dx;
    double b = dt/dx/dx;
    Dleft[0] = 1.0;
    Dleft[N*N-1] = 1.0;
    for (int k=1; k<N-1; ++k) {
        Dleft[k*N + k-1] = -a;
        Dleft[k*N + k]   = 1+b;
        Dleft[k*N + k+1] = -a;

        Dright[k*N + k-1] = a;
        Dright[k*N + k]   = 1-b;
        Dright[k*N + k+1] = a;
    }

    // Determine block and thread amounts
    int grid_dim = ((side_width + 31)/32) ;
    int block_dim = 32;
    dim3 gridDim(grid_dim, grid_dim);
    dim3 blockDim(block_dim, block_dim);

    //copy data from host to device
    magma_dsetmatrix(N, N, U, N, dev_U, N); 
    magma_dsetmatrix(N, N, Dleft, N, dev_Dleft, N);
    magma_dsetmatrix(N, N, Dright, N, dev_Dright, N);

    // LU factorize the left hand operator matrix
    magma_dgetrf_gpu(N, N, dev_Dleft, N, piv, &info);


    double tn = 0; //time counter

    // needed to take first step outside while loop because of some tricky transpose nonsense happening
    tn += dt; 
    // compute explicit step :  Uhat=Dright*U^T
    magmablas_dgemm(MagmaTrans,MagmaNoTrans, N, N, N, 1.0f, dev_Dright, N, dev_U, N, 0.0f, dev_U, N);
    // implicit step solve :  Dleft*U=Uhat
    magma_dgetrs_gpu(MagmaTrans, N, N, dev_Dleft, N, piv, dev_U, N, &info);
    // compute explicit step :  Uhat=Dright*U^T
    magmablas_dgemm(MagmaTrans, MagmaTrans, N, N, N, 1.0f, dev_Dright, N, dev_U, N, 0.0f, dev_U, N);


    printf("GPU matrix U at time %3.3f \n ", tn);
    magma_dprint_gpu(16, 16, dev_U, N);  


    //copy solution from device to host
    magma_dgetmatrix(N, N, dev_U, N, U, N);


    //write data to file
    char filename[256];
    char str_t[128];
    sprintf(str_t, "%d", N );
    sprintf(filename, "ADI_%s.bin", str_t);
    FILE* fileID = fopen(filename, "wb");
    for (int i=0; i<N*N; ++i){
        fwrite(&U[i],sizeof(double),1,fileID);
    }       
    fclose(fileID);

    free(U);
    free(Dleft);
    free(Dright);
    magma_free(dev_U);
    magma_free(dev_Dleft);
    magma_free(dev_Dright);
    free(piv);


    magma_finalize();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: When you talk about "grid size", what do you mean? Is it the value of `side_width`? And are you sure that in-place dot products are supported by `magma_dgemm`? I would be surprised if they were....

Comment: Yes, grid size is the side_width. The 2D domain is discretized into an array of NxN points (N=side_width).  The use of magmablas_dgemm is for matrix-matrix multiplication, not dot product.  Are you suggesting that magma will not do in-place matrix-matrix multiplication? I thought it would follow Lapack and allow assigning to C the value from A*C ?  Why does it work fine with a grid of 128 or less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, BLAS/LAPACK gemm has never supported in-place operations, ie.

```
C := alpha*op( A )*op( B ) + beta*C
```

cannot be transformed into

```
A := alpha*op( A )*op( B ) + beta*A
```

or

```
B := alpha*op( A )*op( B ) + beta*B
```

with any guarantee of correctness, even for the canonical case with `alpha = 1, beta = 0`. If you can follow the fortran, I would recommend having a look at the [reference code](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f_source.html) from the Dongarra group. That implementation will break if the pointer for the matrix passed as C aliaises either A or B.

In multi-threaded or massively parallel BLAS implementations, this is particularly true. Most parallel execution environments don't support any sort of strong or fixed execution ordering. That can mean that operations which *unintentionally* work in serial versions of linear algebra routines break in parallel, because of the lack of execution order guarantee. If a routine in a parallel BLAS or LAPACK implementation doesn't explicitly say it supports in-place operations, don't assume otherwise, because there be dragons and all of that...

Your MAGMA gemm calls only work at small sizes by accident, and probably because very small matrix sizes don't expose enough parallelism to hit the correctness problems that will arise from aliasing an input and output pointer. If you change your code so that the inputs and output are different memory allocations, I suspect the problem will disappear.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you for the thorough explanation. I have my code using a temp matrix rather than writing in place and now it works perfectly. :)